# How to change default time zone in azure website service?

Tags: azure, timezone, azure-web-app-service

I'm new to Azure Web Sites service.
I uploaded my web site files and it works very nice.

But I have a problem with default time zone.
My location is Seoul(+9). But the code return UTC(+0) time when I call below.

```
DateTime.Now;
```

Is there any way to solve this problem without complicated fix like editing Web.config?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It is now possible to change the server time zone for your Azure Websites / Web Apps.

To do this, add an application setting (using the portal) called “WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE” equal to the name of the time zone in question (basically the same string as the key name at HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows Nt\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\).

The list of time zone values is [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/973627/microsoft-time-zone-index-values). Use a value from the column labeled "Name of Time Zone".

Comment: Top marks for a solution which doesn't require code changes. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunate this will not work for databases on Azure. GetDate() in mssql azure database still returns UTC with this setting.

Comment: True, but the question is about Web Apps.

Comment: **WARNING**, as of today (25 May, 2015) this setting does **NOT** work properly. See this diagnostics output that was taken at 9:33 AM UTC http://i.stack.imgur.com/9WyvQ.png after "changing" timezone to EST using this setting.

Comment: source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/waws/archive/2014/08/05/get-the-local-server-time-for-your-azure-web-site.aspx

Comment: Just changed it in my webapps app settings and works fine. For me, UK time is WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE = GMT Standard Time

Comment: @EugeneD.Gubenkov What exact value did you put in your application setting?

Comment: Where did you find it ?? that WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE

Comment: This works for the most part but does not take daylight savings time into consideration.

Comment: I'm struggling to get this to work for British Summer Time. The code seems to ignore a setting with the value "Greenwich Summer Time" or "British Summer Time". If I change it to something like "Easter Standard Time" it does work, so is it possible that there are some timezone settings that are not supported?

Comment: You don't need to explicitly ask for a daylight savings time zone. The DST adjustment will happen automatically if you specify the correct standard time zone.

Comment: "US Eastern Standard Time" for US Eastern with automatic DST

Comment: To get this setting to work for Australian Eastern Standard Time I had to use the value "AUS Eastern Standard Time" instead of the "A.U.S. Eastern Standard Time" recommended in the linked time zone page. I discovered this in the registry. I suspect timezones have been renamed in later versions of Windows.

Answer (score 13):

Changing TimeZone on Azure VMs is not recommended [according to Microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6509833/735446). Instead convert time to local using [methods of TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttimefromutc.aspx) structure.

However at  least one possible solution is mentioned in the [above mentioned post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504153/azure-timezone-utc-problem-how-to-solve).

P.S. an example of solution provided by question author in comment below:

```
DateTime timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
TimeZoneInfo kstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Korea Standard Time"); 
DateTime kstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, kstZone);
```

Comment: DateTime timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
                TimeZoneInfo kstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Korea Standard Time");
                DateTime kstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, kstZone);