# datetime.utcnow returns time 12 hours ago on azure

Tags: datetime, azure

I'm using windows azure server. `Datetime.UtcNow` returns time 12 hours ago. How can I get the time equal to my local time?

**Update:**
On some devices it says 12 hours ago but on some devices it works fine. (both at same place)

Comment: What time zone are you in?

Comment: UTC+05:00 in Pakistan

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504153/migration-from-local-server-to-azure-timezone-utc-how-to-solve

Answer (score 0):

Check the timezone in your VM. You should be able to change that to the timezone you prefer. Another way can be to create the VM with the preconfigured timezone as described [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/6602810-vm-regional-settings-and-timezone).